# Migration NServiceBus from 7.5 to 8: Dependency using WindsorContainer

Tags: dependency-injection, migration, castle-windsor, nservicebus

We are using NServiceBus version 7.5 and Windsor Container. We load dependencies to a Windsor container. The dependencies are (for example) from loading FromAssemblyContaining. We load existing Windsor container like that:

`endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<WindsorBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(container));.`

Everything works quite well. But now we need to migrate NServiceBus to version 8. Where `UseContainer` is not supported any more. In NServiceBus 8, we have to load dependencies through `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped` or `AddTransient`.
How do I load all necessary dependencies (the existing container). Listing all Services in the old code (load from `FromAssemblyContaining`) is impossible.

Thank you very much!

I tried something as here https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/7to8/dependency-injection:

```cs
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("EndpointName");
_endpointCustomization.Customize(endpointConfiguration); //setup things for endpoint
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
var container =  _endpointCustomization.Container()  // my function to load existing Windsor container
var serviceProvider = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, serviceCollection);
var startableEndpoint = EndpointWithExternallyManagedContainer.Create(endpointConfiguration, serviceCollection);
var _endpointInstance = await startableEndpoint.Start(serviceProvider);
await _endpointCustomization.Start(_endpointInstance);
```

It throws exception at the first await call "No component for supporting the service NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.MessageMetadataRegistry was found" Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is finalizing the Windsor container already before calling `EndpointWithExternallyManagedContainer.Create(endpointConfiguration, serviceCollection);`. `Create` will add NServiceBus specific registration to the ServiceCollection which will then not be reflected to the service provider instance that you already created. Try the following instead:

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("EndpointName");
_endpointCustomization.Customize(endpointConfiguration); //setup things for endpoint

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
var startableEndpoint = EndpointWithExternallyManagedContainer.Create(endpointConfiguration, serviceCollection);

var container =  _endpointCustomization.Container()  // my function to load existing Windsor container
var serviceProvider = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, serviceCollection);
var _endpointInstance = await startableEndpoint.Start(serviceProvider);
await _endpointCustomization.Start(_endpointInstance);
```

Since I don't know what your `_endpointCustomization` instance is doing exactly, I don't know whether that will solve the issues but this suggestion represents the order the endpoint should be configured (also documented here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/7to8/dependency-injection#externally-managed-container-mode-migrating-to-externally-managed-mode-castle-windsor)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now I am able to use my existing Windsor container (with loading dependencies) from our NServiceBus 7.5 to use in NServiceBus 8. 
I think I missed nuget package, Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection, in my project. After adding nuget Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection to the project, it now can start the container with dependencies